# Invariant probability vector as a left eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes

What is the probability in the long run that the chain is in state 1? Solve this by directly computing the invariant probability vector as a left eigenvector.

\begin{bmatrix}
.4 &.2 &.4 \\ 
.6  &0&  .4 \\ 
 .2 &.5& .3  
\end{bmatrix}

Please note that this is a 3x3 probability matrix. Specifically I need help with the linear algebra aspect of this. Thanks!

Comment: can you at least setup this problem?

Comment: Yes I can set the problem up. But my problem is going through and diagonalizing the matrix.

Comment: What eigenvalues did you get

Comment: 1 and 1-p-q

can I just solve for [x y z] * P = [x y z] ? It seems like a pretty simple system of equations if that will work

Comment: That will work. Just don't forget your eigenvector needs to be normalized since its a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The invariant probability vector is a left-eigenvector associated with the maximal positive eigenvalue, which in this case is $\lambda = 1$.

Your answer should be:

> $\frac{25}{66} \approx 0.38$